# Slider toggle button in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I would like to add one of these slider toggle buttons to my react native app. Are there any easy ways to do this without starting from scratch?

[Example video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jked.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code snippet instead of video

Comment: I don’t have a code snippet, that’s the point. I want to know if there’s a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is make the background can be animated.

[image]

[See the sample i've created.](https://snack.expo.io/@thainq00/slide-button)

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, this is the whole idea, animated background :DD

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you. I made it a bit smaller and added some drop shadow and it looks perfect, thanks! My snack: https://snack.expo.io/@marccashmore/slide-button

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic example of how you can achieve this using `Animated` API.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {
    Animated,
    Easing,
    StyleSheet,
    Pressable,
    View,
    Text,
  } from 'react-native';

  const App = () => {
    const animatedValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

      const startAnimation = (toValue) => {
        Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
          toValue,
          duration: 400,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      };

      const left = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['2%', '50%'],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
      });

      const scale = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
        outputRange: [1, 0.9, 1],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
      });

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.slider, { left }]} />
            <Pressable
              style={styles.clickableArea}
              onPress={startAnimation.bind(null, 0)}>
              <Animated.Text
                style={[styles.sliderText, { transform: [{ scale }] }]}>
                Active
              </Animated.Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              style={styles.clickableArea}
              onPress={startAnimation.bind(null, 1)}>
              <Animated.Text
                style={[styles.sliderText, { transform: [{ scale }] }]}>
                History
              </Animated.Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      );      
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      sliderContainer: {
        width: '90%',
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
      },
      clickableArea: {
        width: '50%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      sliderText: {
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: '500',
      },
      slider: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '48%',
        height: '90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
      },
    });

    export default App;
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/jsZDorQWG) you can check out the demo of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

use native base tabs and then customize them .

this link will help you

```
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref
```